# Expand div from the middle instead of just top and left using CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I thought it would be cool using CSS transforms to create an effect where a div expands from its center to a predetermined height and width, rather than just from the upper left corner.

For instance, if I have ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/xcWge/))

```
<div id="square"></div>
```

and (vendor prefixes left out for brevity)

```
#square {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: blue;
    transition: width 1s, height 1s;
}
#square:hover {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

On hover, this will expand the square to the right and down to 100px. **I would like to have it expand from the middle.**

I'm aware that I could probably use `transform: scale(x)` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/xcWge/3/)), but this doesn't really provide me with a very "pixel perfect" layout (as it is percentage-based), and it also does not affect the surrounding layout (make other elements that are in the document flow adjust to its resizing). This is essentially what I want to do, except with the document flow affected accordingly.

Does anyone know of a way to do this **without javascript**?

Comment: i think you will need javascript or jQuery todo what you want

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The key is to transition the margin by a formula. There is a little "wiggle" that is annoying during the transition if it is floated.

**EDITED ADDING OPTIONS**

***Option 1***: Expands within space reserved around it http://jsfiddle.net/xcWge/14/:

```
#square {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 100px; /*for centering purposes*/
    -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
    -ms-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
    transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
}
#square:hover {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 55px; /* initial margin - (width change (and/or height change)/2), so here 100px is initial margin, and the change is (100px final W/H - 10px initial W/H = 90px change, so 100px - (90px / 2 [= 45px]) = 55px) */
}
```

***Option 2***: Expands over elements around it http://jsfiddle.net/xcWge/18/:

```
#square {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0; /*for centering purposes*/
    -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
    -ms-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
    transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
}
#square:hover {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    margin: -50px; /* 0 - (110px - 10px [= 100px]) / 2 =  -50px */
}
```

***Option 3***: Expands over elements before it in flow and shifts elements after it http://jsfiddle.net/xcWge/22/:

```
#square {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s, top 1s, left 1s, margin 1s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s, height 1s, top 1s, left 1s, margin 1s;
    -ms-transition: width 1s, height 1s, top 1s, left 1s, margin 1s ;
    transition: width 1s, height 1s, top 1s, left 1s, margin 1s;
}
#square:hover {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    top: -50px; /* initial top[0] - (new height[110px] - initial height[10px] [=100px])/2 [=50px] = -50px) */
    left: -50px; /* initial left[0] - (new width[110px] - initial width[10px] [=100px])/2 [=50px] = -50px) */
    margin-right: -50px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

**ADDED NON-SQUARE EXAMPLE**

A comment was made this does not work for a non-square (same width/height), but that just means one has to adjust differently for each direction during the transition. So here is ***Option 2 (with non-square)*** that starts as a rectangle, and the width expands twice as much as the height (so changes rectangle shape even) during the transition: Expands over elements around it http://jsfiddle.net/xcWge/2131/

```
#rectangle {
    width: 110px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0; /*for centering purposes*/
    -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
    -ms-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
    transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
}
#rectangle:hover {
    width: 310px;
    height: 110px;
    margin: -50px -100px; /* initial margin - ((initial margin - width change (or height change))/2) */
}
```

If the `width` were only changing by 100px also (so from 110px to 210px), then just a `margin: -50px` would have still worked.

Comment: so how about if there are no margins? in my actual code, the element has no margins :\

Comment: @Jason--You need to transition into negative margins. See http://jsfiddle.net/xcWge/18/

Comment: so this is awesome, and so close to what i'm looking for. the last bit is **not** that the stuff around it stays still, but that it actually adjusts to the size of the element. I can effectively achieve what you're doing with scale (for the most part). but i want the stuff around it (in flow) to adjust their positions as well.

Comment: I doubt you can get that completely. For the float example, you can affect the elements after it, but not before it, animating `top` and `left` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/xcWge/20/. The problem is the elements prior to it determine the hover squares position, it does not determine there's.

Comment: @Jason--the problem is (as stated in my comment above), to get the element above and the one floating left to move, they need to have negative margin applied to them as part of the transition, but there is no way to target them via css on a hover of the square.

Comment: i'm actually not worried about the stuff before, just next to and below :) i think i may be able to get this worked out. when i do, i'll mark this. thanks!

Comment: @Jason--My other example forgot to adjust the margin for the relative position. This one works to correct adjust the position of elements following: http://jsfiddle.net/xcWge/22/

Comment: using your idea, i got it to work. it was a lot easier than i expected. thank you!

Comment: ScottS The example is awesome to be taken at its face value. But doesn't seem to work when resulting width and height are different from each other. I need to display an initial small box/dialog to get an input from a user and then to expand it to cover around 95% of a Browser's surface/viewport. Could you add such an example?

Comment: @azakgaim: **if width and height are different, then you just need to adjust top/bottom (for height) and left/right (for width) margins *differently* to get a centered expansion.** I'm a bit unclear exactly what your planned interaction of the `input` is with the expansion, and it may be that what you want to do is not possible by css only, but here is an example of a `div` hiding behind a centered `input` where the `div` expands on the `:focus` of the `input` to 95% of the screen size (I did not test in all browsers): [http://jsfiddle.net/e0atcndc/55/](http://jsfiddle.net/e0atcndc/55/)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to transition it's position in order to do this as well, setting it to relative/absolute and changing the `top` value as it animates.

(edit based on comment)

Instead of absolute positioning, you could try to do the same sort of thing with a negative top margin. That would keep it in the document flow. Somehow, though, you need to actually move the div as well as animating the height/width.

Comment: so yeah that's the same problem with using `scale()` because that takes it out of the document flow. i want the rest of the document to adjust to its resizing.

Comment: +1 because your added comment about margins helped me come up with my solution.

Answer (score 1):

you may have to make you're div position absolute and then adjust the left and top position on hover. [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/QcgEv/)

Comment: so try adding a vendor prefix to your transition and see what happens :) also, this is still giving the effect of expanding from the top left :\

Answer (score 0):

I do this by adjusting the top and left alignment on hover also. Ex: i'll add 50 px to the width and move it left 25px to give the over all effect of it expaning from the middle.