# animation expanding wiggle

Tags: jquery, animation, hover, expand, vibration

in this menu, de hovered div is expanding and all the other elements are shrinking

there is a small wiggle at the right side of the menu when changing size, which is really annoying

i've seen this: [Expand div from the middle instead of just top and left using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451909/expand-div-from-the-middle-instead-of-just-top-and-left-using-css)
expanding from the center, and they also mention the wiggle

is there a way to fix the wiggle?

this is my code

as you can see the speed is always the same so there shouldnt be a wiggle in theory

```
function add() {
    var speed = 50;
    $('.space').hover(
        function() {
            var n = this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
            $('#space_' + n).removeClass('contract');
            $('#space_' + n).stop().animate({
                height: "107px",
                width: "107px",
            }, speed, 'linear');
            $('.contract').stop().animate({
                height: "73px",
                width: "70px",
            }, speed, 'linear');
        },
        function() {
            var n = this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
            $('#space_' + n).addClass('contract');
            if($('#space_' + n).hasClass('selected') != true) {
                $('#space_' + n).stop().animate({
                    height: "73px",
                    width: "73px",
                }, speed, 'linear');
            }
            $('.contract').stop().animate({
                height: "73px",
                width: "73px",
            }, speed, 'linear');
        }
    );
}

add();
```

here you can see an example of the menu:  http://mellroy.com/dean/

thank you in advance

Comment: Notice that there is no wiggle if you're only moving across two elements at a time, because their animations and sizes will be in sync.  I think the problem is when you're swapping across three or more items, and might be caused by one of: 1) multiple animations that don't properly add up on every frame 2) maybe not a perfect alignment of frames and mouse callbacks, so the multiple animations temporarily don't add up.  I'm not terribly experienced with how the animation/mouse even code in jQuery works, so not sure what guarantees they make.

Comment: I'm thinking unfortunately that the easiest guaranteed solution will be to manually calculate all the sizes and animate each item yourself, and evaluate them all as a whole.  Anything else will rely on perfect mouse event/animation sync.

Comment: Actually never mind about the two elements at a time.  It also happens if you move the mouse quickly in and out of the field across a single item.  But I still think the manually calculating all positions, and setting the items as "absolute", "fixed", or "relative" rather than letting the layout engine do your work for you will be the only sure solution.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the borders - rather use a background image. If you place the entire menu on a white and black background (matching the menu), you wont see the wobble - event though the wobble is still there. I doubt you will be able to avoid it.