# incredibly slow and choppy jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So I have been creating a simple animation that copies a div, and expands it over the window.  I am trying to optimize it so it's less choppy and was wondering if someone could help me out.  So I have been reading that you cannot have any padding or margin settings on the element that is being animated, because that will slow everything down.    This is the animation function I am using:

```
$('.content_cell').on('click', function(event) {
        var $clonedElement = $( this ).clone(true).attr('class','cloned_object content_cell').appendTo('#mainContentTable');
        $clonedElement.css({left:$(this).position().left, 
                            top:$(this).position().top, 
                            opacity:0}) ;

        //Position caching for closing animation
        selectedPos = $(this).position();           
        var currPos= $('#invitedToChatCell').position();

        //Now animate the cloned element to the correct size
        $clonedElement.animate({
            height:640, width:700, 
            //position:'absolute', 
            left:currPos.left, 
            top:currPos.top, 
            opacity:1.0 
        }, 500, function(){ $('.cloned_object > ul').toggle(); });
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

The content cell CSS and cloned_object css look like this

```
.content_cell {
   border-style: solid;
   cursor:pointer;
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
   overflow:auto;
}

.cloned_object{
   position:absolute;
   background-color:white;
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
}
```

does anyone see why this is such a slow animation?  or anything I could do to speed it up?  Thanks in advance...

UPDATE:
Here is a JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/neK8g/)

Comment: If you can make it a habit to link a working example from http://www.jsfiddle.net it would help a lot =)

Comment: Ohh good idea... It looks like the site is down now though?  Or is that just me?

Comment: jsfiddle is a little overloaded at times. Just keep trying.

Comment: NVM, got in. Just took longer then usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than just simple JQuery animations tend to be "laggy".
I use css-animations/css-transforms wherever possible.

What you can do is clone the div with jquery and put it on the screen with some new css classes. Let the css handle the expand-part.

For css examples and good ideas see: http://daneden.me/animate

Just found another thread about this which explains the css part: [Expand div from the middle instead of just top and left using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451909/expand-div-from-the-middle-instead-of-just-top-and-left-using-css)

Comment: Unfortuantely, this won't work in IE8 will it, since it's a lot of css3 stuff

Comment: True. IE-8 should be banned anyways :p

Comment: Hahaha, I know.  I have actually gotten an an animation to do what I need using CSS3 and then wrote a fork :X to handle the older IE's.  Unfortunately, the same code behaves totally differently in chrome and FF.  It's driving me up a wall.  Now I know what it must have been like in the early web!  >:(