# enlarging a div that is inside a drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a pure CSS and HTML menu that 'pops-out' at you when you mouse over.

I just cant find the solution to making it pop out from the center, without changing the size of the `ul`. What I need is for the `div` to enlarge from the center, without changing its surroundings or moving up.

I have found and read through this *SO* question -- [Expand div from the middle instead of just top and left using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451909/expand-div-from-the-middle-instead-of-just-top-and-left-using-css) -- and I am trying to implement @ScottS second option.

This is the code i have so far - http://jsfiddle.net/HTgCN/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, your code works just fine.
the only thing you have to change is the margin property in `div.menu:hover` to -5px

```
margin: -5px;
```

However if you want to make it bigger with more than 10px, you will have to change the margin too.

Comment: Thanks for that. Just wondering if there was any way to stop the div shaking?

Comment: well, it's shaking when your mouse is on the edge. that's because when the div moves out with 1px from under your mouse, the hover rules doesn't apply any more and tries to get back to it's place. Then the hover rules apply again and so on. I would use jQuery animate for this tho. or maybe I misunderstood the question?