# expand div from middle, but unequal widths to each side?

Tags: css, width, css-transitions

i want to expand a div (on hover) from its parent's placement in the container to a set width that must fill my entire first row. THIS IS KINDA HARD TO PUT INTO WORDS SO this is the code in question:

```
#info {
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:0;
    transition-duration:0.5s;  
    -moz-transition-duration:0.5s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.5s;  
    -o-transition-duration:0.5s; }

#icon:hover #info {
    opacity:1;
    width:665px;
    transition:opacity 0.5s, width 0.5s ease 0.5s;  
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.5s, width 0.5s ease 0.5s; 
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s, width 0.5s ease 0.5s; 
    -o-transition:opacity 0.5s, width 0.5s ease 0.5s;  }
```

and [here's a fiddle with what i have so far.](http://jsfiddle.net/ULpmw/3/)

as you can see, the div #info in the first square in each row expand to the width i'd like them to, and the end result is what i'd like the bar to look like within the container for every square i hover over. the next squares in the same row expand to my desired width but they expand left only- i want them to expand left AND right so that they fill up the first row like the first square's div #info on hover does.

the second option in the answer to this question: [Expand div from the middle instead of just top and left using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451909/expand-div-from-the-middle-instead-of-just-top-and-left-using-css) is a similar concept to what i am trying to achieve but it expands from the middle to equidistant left and right lengths- that wouldn't work with my layout because of the different placements of the parent divs within their row.

and if possible, i'd like to achieve this with just css! if someone does have a javascript solution, please give me step by step instructions omg i'm horrible with javascript.

Comment: for a non js, can you use nth-child and assign width for each square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<edit>`**[last fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/ULpmw/10/)** `</edit>`

---

If,

1. boxes are always same size
2. not too many
3. always 4 on each row

You can set a negative margin either way:

1. dispatch a different class (3 or 4) to your boxes
2. or use nth-child(n) in css file

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ULpmw/4/)** with nth-child(n) method [(demo updated with transition)](http://jsfiddle.net/ULpmw/5/)

```
#icon:nth-child(2):hover #info, #icon:nth-child(6):hover #info {
    margin-left:-170px;
}
#icon:nth-child(3):hover #info, #icon:nth-child(7):hover #info {
    margin-left:-350px;
}
#icon:nth-child(4n):hover #info {
    margin-left:-530px;
}
```

More boxes ? , update selectors or it might be time to uses [class](http://jsfiddle.net/ULpmw/6/).

Comment: THANK YOU!! i do have another question though- to make the grid look a little more symmetrical, i made icons 3 and 4 expand their div #info to the left instead of to the right, which is default. but i'm having a lot of trouble making the 3rd icon's #info move to the right end of the row on hover (like the effect of the 2nd icons, but for the 3rd icons i want it to move to the right. [here's a fiddle with my updated code!](http://jsfiddle.net/ULpmw/9/)

Comment: @ampora well for opposite effect, use opposite direction : margin-right:-177px; http://jsfiddle.net/ULpmw/10/ ;)

Comment: WOW that was painfully obvious ;___; thank u again omg I HAVE 1 MORE QUESTION i hope it will be the last one (sorry for asking for so much omg) but i see an unrelated problem in the fiddle- when i hover over the 1st icon in a row and then i hover in the div #info to the space above the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th icon, THEIR respective div #info shows up. how can i make it so that if i hover over any icon for its div #info, its #info will stay there and hovering over another icon in the row won't make ITS div #info show up? i tried adding a high-number z-index to #info but that didn't do anything.

Comment: @ampora hello, maybe pointer-events can help : http://jsfiddle.net/ULpmw/13/ , mouse will see through.

Comment: oh gosh it turns out that i just added the z-index in the wrong place- it had to go in #icon:nth-child(4n+n):hover #info { instead. but thank you for your help with everything!! i haven't heard of pointer-events before; maybe it will be of good use in my future projects. :)