# CSS: How to scale an image from the center instead of top-left

Tags: css, scale, center, transition

So my problem is that I have an image and I set its CSS to have a

```
max-width: 100%
```

which scales it at lower resolutions ( as will be seen in the fiddle below ). What I want is for the transition to take effect from the center of the image.

Currently; and from what I have seen from most the transitions I have done involving scale they expand from the top-left corner.

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Eolis/3ya98xh8/3/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expand div from the middle instead of just top and left using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451909/expand-div-from-the-middle-instead-of-just-top-and-left-using-css)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just replace `width: 400px;` with [`transform: scale(2,2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) on `:hover`.

```css
img {
    width: 100%; max-width: 100%;
}
div {
    position: absolute; left: 20%; top: 20%;
    width: 250px;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
div:hover {
    transform: scale(2,2)
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="http://photobucket.com/images/cat" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://i583.photobucket.com/albums/ss278/campipr/coolcat.gif" border="0" alt="cat photo: cat coolcat.gif"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: transform-origin: center; ?

Comment: @oCcSking it is the default value  `Default value: 50% 50% 0` as in Specifications   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin        `Initial value 50% 50% 0`.

Answer (score 9):

Add this to the `div:hover`:

```
transform: translateX(-25%) translateY(-25%);
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ya98xh8/4/

Comment: oh I see. that is quite nice. not perfect but it could be perfected with appropriate % values. thanks! this also gave me an Idea to use margins and I have updated my fiddle using another method here: http://jsfiddle.net/Eolis/3ya98xh8/5/

Comment: It should have been perfect but I dont know why it is shifting a bit.

Comment: Here is a better way: http://jsfiddle.net/3ya98xh8/6/. Here you dont have to use any hardcoded values.

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget to set transform-origin

```css
.current{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    transition: opacity 1.6s ease-out 0s, transform 7.2s linear 0s;
    transform-origin: center center;
    animation: normal;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/

Answer (score 1):

may as well throw my solution up in case it is helpful to anyone:

**::CSS::**

```
img {
    width: 100%; max-width: 100%;
}
div {
    position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%;
    margin-left: -125px; margin-top: -100px;
    width: 250px;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
div:hover {
    margin-left: -200px; margin-top: -150px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

**::HTML::**

```
<div>
    <a href="http://photobucket.com/images/cat" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://i583.photobucket.com/albums/ss278/campipr/coolcat.gif" border="0" alt="cat photo: cat coolcat.gif"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

**::Fiddle::**
http://jsfiddle.net/Eolis/3ya98xh8/5/

Comment: Here is a better way: http://jsfiddle.net/3ya98xh8/6. Here you dont have to use any hardcoded values.