# When setting an element's fontsize w/ transition, how to resize from the center

Tags: javascript, css

So I am currently making a age counter app
[image]

And something that I would like to do is make the numbers pop every time they increase.

I have tried a few different techniques, and have got something working-- but there is a problem.

So here is my current solution, in my .js:

```
  setInterval(this.bubbleNumber.bind(this),1000);

  App.fn.bubbleNumber = function()
  {
    var hour = $('hour-placeholder');
    if(hour)
    {
      hour.style.fontSize="7vw";
      hour.style.webkitTransition=".1s ease-in-out";
      setTimeout(function(){
        hour.style.fontSize="6vw";
        hour.style.webkitTransition=".6s ease-in-out";
      }, 500);
    }
  };
```

This works, but the problem is that when the resizing occurs, the number resizes from the top left corner if I have the number left justified, and the top right corner if I have the number right justified.  I would like to change the font size w/ transition, and do it from the center.

I'm pretty sure with my current implementation this isn't possible, in fact I'm almost certain that I'm going to have to switch to using jQuery's [animate()](http://jsfiddle.net/4beEM/10/) on CSS3's [transform (scale)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726430/css-how-to-scale-an-image-from-the-center-instead-of-top-left). 
I don't really understand the [difference](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/css3_animations_vs_transitions.htm) between "CSS animations" and "JavaScript animations", because to me it looks like JavaScript just ends up using CSS animations anyways? So I really just am not sure which avenue I should go down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the container of the digit is big enough to contain the enlarged digit. Position the digit in the center of the container by giving the digit a margin set in vw.
Then, when the script changes the font size from 6vw to 7vw, decrease the margin by 0.5vw and give the margin the same transition time. That should keep the digit centered during the transition.
You could also use relative or absolute positioning instead of a margin; in that case, position the digit by setting top and left, and animate both top and left.