# How to zoom in keeping object's center in place?

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to make it zoom in from center rather than from top-left corner.
I've tried `transform: scale(2,2)`, and `transform: translateX(-25%) translateY(-25%)`, as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726430/css-how-to-scale-an-image-from-the-center-instead-of-top-left), neither seem to do anything at all.
Is there any alternative to `scale`? It doesn't seem to be working in Chrome.
Maybe it has something to do with the container that it's in? I'm not sure. I tried changing the `top` and `left` coordinates to account for the movement of the center when the animation plays, but that also didn't help.

```css
 .box2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 40em;
  height: 20em;
 }

   .box2 > .content {
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
    opacity: 1.0;
    margin: 0;
   }

   .box2.inactive > .content {
    opacity: 0;
   }


 .circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
  opacity: 1;
 
 }

  .circle.circle1 {
   top: 4em;
   left: 6em;
   width: 5em;
   height: 5em;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  .circle.circle2 {
   top: 10em;
   left: 20em;
   width: 3em;
   height: 3em;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }

.circle:hover {
    width: 10em;
 height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="box2">
<div class="circle circle1"></div>
</div>
</html>
```

Looks like this in Microsoft Edge with `scale(2,2)` and doesn't animate at all in Chrome:
[image]

Comment: .circle:hover {
  transform: scale(2,2);
}

not working?it's worked for me

Comment: @AliNaeimi doesn't work for me :( ... Just tried it in Microsoft Edge and it works. But not in Chrome

Comment: And in ME it zooms in and then snaps back to the original size for some reason.

Comment: look at Browser Support from this link:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Just updated Chrome. Still same :\

Answer (score 0):

You can set `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` for `.circle` - it shifts the circle left and up relatively to its starting point and thus the point set in the center of circle.

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    
  background: green;
  opacity: 1;
 }

.circle.circle1 {
  top: 8em;
   left: 12em;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
 }
.circle:hover {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<html><div class="circle circle1"></div></html>
```

Comment: it works here, but for some reason not when I try it on my page :( why could that be?