# Positioning Parallax Hover Layers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax.js

I'm teaching myself how to create a parallax hover image using 5 layers, which is working perfectly, and I am able to resize the layers alright, but I'm having trouble with the positioning.

When resized to 150vw/vh the layers spill over the bottom and right side. I've tried a few things but not sure if I'm putting the css properties in the right place. 100vh/vw positions in the center but is too small for my header.

Should I be positioning in #scene or .img? And whats best practice for this kind of thing?

Heres what I have so far anyway:

```
<div class="section--parallax">

<div id="scene">
  <div data-depth="0.2">
  <img src="resources/img/layer1.png">
  </div>
  <div data-depth="0.6">
  <img src="resources/img/layer2.png">
  </div>
  <div data-depth="0.3">
  <img src="resources/img/layer3.png">
  </div>
  <div data-depth="0.6">
  <img src="resources/img/layer4.png">
  </div>
  <div data-depth="0.2">
  <img src="resources/img/layer5.png">
  </div>

</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
header {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;

}

#scene {


}

.section--parallax img {
    width: 150vw;
    height: 150vh;

}
```

JS

```
var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
var parallaxInstance = new Parallax(scene);
```

Comment: To clarify, you'd like the parallax to be able to move within your header element, so making the layers match the size of the header means that they can move in a way that you can see the edges of the layers, which isn't what you want. However, making them much larger than the header means that you can't see all of the layers. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I'd like it to consume the header space as much as possible. I have text which centers in the middle of the layers and then the parallax surrounds it. The text is separate and doesn't move. But when I resive the parallax layers it expands towards the bottom corner rather than out from the center.

Comment: does this help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726430/css-how-to-scale-an-image-from-the-center-instead-of-top-left

Comment: Yes, I had to mess around with it but working better now, thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working