# Transition animation need some CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I am trying to make a page load transition effective div. This is my [**DEMO FULL PAGE**](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/full/eNZRqp/) full page from codepen.io and also this is example page with code **[DEMO WITH CODE](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/eNZRqp)**

If you open the demo full page then you can see there is a one image and this image opening with transition animation. But there is something went wrong.

When page load the image opening transition but it is opening up to bottom . I want to open it in the middle, without any deviation.

Anyone can help me in this regard ? How can i fixed it ?

This is my CSS code:

```
.test {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.testtransition {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.testtransition img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-animation: scale 0.8s;
  /* Firefox */

  -webkit-animation: scale 0.8s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */

  -o-animation: scale 0.8s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: scale 0.9s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */

  -moz-animation: scale 0.9s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */

  -ms-animation: scale 0.9s;
  /* Internet Explorer */

  -o-animation: scale 0.9s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */

  animation: scale 0.9s;
}

@keyframes scale {
  from {
    width: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes scale {
  /* Firefox */

  from {
    width: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale {
  /* Safari and Chrome */

  from {
    width: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes scale {
  /* Opera */

  from {
    width: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451909/expand-div-from-the-middle-instead-of-just-top-and-left-using-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a working pen](http://codepen.io/ntdb/pen/EjKvaN). A summary of my changes:

- Added `text-align: center` on `.testtransition` to keep the image centered
- Added `width`, `height`, and `padding` to the animation to keep the image centered throughout the animation
- Removed the `width` parameter from the `img` tag to keep things simple :)

Comment: Thanks for your clean answer. I really understood what i need to do for it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @innovation you bet! Please mark it as correct if it fixed things properly.

Comment: The site said wait for upvote 2 minutes  :)). I am waiting on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick! You need to set a from and to in each animation.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJZvJB

```
.testtransition {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.testtransition img {
  -webkit-animation: scaleAnim 1s;
  -moz-animation: scaleAnim 1s;
  -o-animation: scaleAnim 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleAnim {
  from { -webkit-transform: scale(0) }
  to { -webkit-transform: scale(1) }
}

@-moz-keyframes scaleAnim {
  from { -moz-transform: scale(0) }
  to { -moz-transform: scale(1) }
}

@-o-keyframes scaleAnim {
  from { -o-transform: scale(0)}
  to { -o-transform: scale(1)}
}
```

You may have to play with the initial image to maintain an attractive circle, for now i've added backface-visibility.