# Resize animation from the center on a hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, animation, hover

I have this animation, on the hover the size on my span is bigger.
But i would like that the animation beginning from the center of the mouse.

How I can do ?

https://jsfiddle.net/telman/9rrbzwem/

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $("span").css({left:e.pageX - 50, top:e.pageY - 50});
});


$("div").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.5"}, 0);
    $("span").stop().animate({"height": "100px", "width": "100px"}, 200);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 0);
    $("span").stop().animate({"height": "0px", "width": "0px"}, 200);
  }
);
```

Comment: Your `div` doesn't change size at all. Do you mean the red `span`?

Comment: Yes this is the span

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand div from the middle instead of just top and left using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451909/expand-div-from-the-middle-instead-of-just-top-and-left-using-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you just need to animate the `margin` along with the `width` and `height` to make the centre point of the element match the cursor. When the element is hidden the margin should be 50% of the final width, and when the animation ends the margin should be `0`. Try this:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $("span").css({
    left: e.pageX - 50,
    top: e.pageY - 50
  });
});

$("div").hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 0);
  $("span").stop().animate({
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    margin: 0 // changed
  }, 200);
}, function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 0);
  $("span").stop().animate({
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    margin: 50 // changed
  }, 200);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 100px;
}
span {
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  pointer-events: none;
  margin: 50px; /* changed */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you also have to animate the position of the span. When you start animating the height and width of span is set to 0, and you already set the position to mouseCurrentPosition-50. So in this case animation starts from -50 top and -50 left. So please try this once, may be it helps you.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
$("span").css({left:e.pageX-50 , top:e.pageY -50});
});


$("div").hover(
  function(e) {
  $("span").css({left:e.pageX , top:e.pageY });
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.5"}, 0);
    $("span").stop().animate({
    "height": "100px",
    "width": "100px",
    "left":e.pageX-50 ,
    "top":e.pageY-50
    }, 200);
  },
  function(e) {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 0);
    $("span").stop().animate({"height": "0px",
    "width": "0px",
     "left":e.pageX ,
    "top":e.pageY
    }, 200);
  }
);
```

Best of luck :)