# CSS Animation - Grow from center (Zoom from center dot to full container)

Tags: css, animation, css-transforms

I'm working on a game and I want to animate some boxes.

I want a box to start from small and then grow outwards, with all edges growing at the same time in an effect that looks like it is growing outwards from the center.

The best animation I have so far is the following: it grows the height and the width of the box as I want, but starts from the left and top. I would like it to start from a center point.

I looked at the animation properties on W3 and nothing seems to fit the boat.

```
  .box_2_gen{
    
    animation-duration: 0.25s;
    animation-name: createBox;

    position: relative;

    background: #FFEDAD;

    border: black solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 15px;

    width: 98px;
    height: 98px;

    margin: 10px;

    float: left;
}



@keyframes createBox{
    from{
        height:0px;
        width: 0px;

    }
    to{
        height: 98px;
        width: 98px;
    }
}
```

EDIT: My question may seem like another similar one, but I just wanted to know how to do it using only keyframes.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand div from the middle instead of just top and left using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451909/expand-div-from-the-middle-instead-of-just-top-and-left-using-css)

Comment: Fair, and I have seen that solution but I wanted to use a keyframe approach. However, as seen by the answer below, it seems to be a mix of transform and keyframe.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You should use `transform` in the animation for better performance and more control. Then you won't have to repeat the static `px` values, and you can use `transform-origin` to control where the transform happens. `scale()` will scale from the center by default.

```css
div {
  background: red;
  animation: createBox .25s;
  width: 98px; height: 98px;
}
@keyframes createBox {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I wanted. I may have been looking at the wrong resources though. Is it possible to also get a link for further reading?

Comment: Here's the [MDN page on `transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform). Also, [this page](https://engineering.gosquared.com/optimising-60fps-everywhere-in-javascript) mentions how `transform` is better than animating positions and `height` / `width` directly (on _"Layers, compositing, CPU and GPU"_).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a full-size example. I created it for myself, while playing around with Michael Coker's StackSnippet - but thought I'd share after all.

```js
/*  Look Carefully: This is NOT jQuery  */
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
$('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
  $('button').style.display = 'none';
  $('div').style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
/*  All You Need  */
p {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin:0;
  background: red;
  animation: createBox .5s;
  width: 100vw; height: 100vh;
}
@keyframes createBox {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}


/* Extras for this Demo */
body{margin:0;} /*  Required for StackSnippet Container  */
div{
  display:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
p{
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
aside{
  height: 50vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
button{
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
sup{
font-size: .9rem;
}
```

```html
<div><p>Hit the Run Code Snippet button again to re-run</p></div>
<aside><button>Show Me<br><sup>(Best viewed "Full Page")</sup></button></aside>
```