# Material UI after updating throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'muiName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I updated `"material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.38"` to `"@material-ui/core": "^1.3.0"`. I've changed imports, run npm install, removed `node_modules` even `package-lock.json` but I still receive the vague error message `TypeError: Cannot read property 'muiName' of undefined`.

The information about muiName can be found [here in the documentation](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/) but it seems not related to my issue which is caused by update.

The error has been once reported [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8461) but closed due to lack of the details.

Does anybody know what can cause it?

Here are the detailed logs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'muiName' of undefined
isMuiElement
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/@material-ui/core/utils/reactHelpers.js:31
  28 | }
  29 | 
  30 | function isMuiElement(element, muiNames) {
> 31 |   return _react.default.isValidElement(element) && muiNames.indexOf(element.type.muiName) !== -1;
  32 | }
  33 | 
  34 | function isMuiComponent(element, muiNames) {
View compiled
(anonymous function)
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/@material-ui/core/FormControl/FormControl.js:135
  132 | 
  133 | if (children) {
  134 |   _react.default.Children.forEach(children, function (child) {
> 135 |     if (!(0, _reactHelpers.isMuiElement)(child, ['Input', 'Select', 'NativeSelect'])) {
  136 |       return;
  137 |     }
  138 | 
View compiled
forEachSingleChild
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:881
  878 |   var func = bookKeeping.func,
  879 |       context = bookKeeping.context;
  880 | 
> 881 |   func.call(context, child, bookKeeping.count++);
  882 | }
  883 | 
  884 | /**
View compiled
traverseAllChildrenImpl
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:785
  782 | }
  783 | 
  784 | if (invokeCallback) {
> 785 |   callback(traverseContext, children,
  786 |   // If it's the only child, treat the name as if it was wrapped in an array
  787 |   // so that it's consistent if the number of children grows.
  788 |   nameSoFar === '' ? SEPARATOR + getComponentKey(children, 0) : nameSoFar);
View compiled
traverseAllChildren
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:856
  853 |     return 0;
  854 |   }
  855 | 
> 856 |   return traverseAllChildrenImpl(children, '', callback, traverseContext);
  857 | }
  858 | 
  859 | /**
View compiled
forEachChildren [as forEach]
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:901
  898 |     return children;
  899 |   }
  900 |   var traverseContext = getPooledTraverseContext(null, null, forEachFunc, forEachContext);
> 901 |   traverseAllChildren(children, forEachSingleChild, traverseContext);
  902 |   releaseTraverseContext(traverseContext);
  903 | }
  904 | 
View compiled
new FormControl
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/@material-ui/core/FormControl/FormControl.js:134
  131 | var children = _this.props.children;
  132 | 
  133 | if (children) {
> 134 |   _react.default.Children.forEach(children, function (child) {
  135 |     if (!(0, _reactHelpers.isMuiElement)(child, ['Input', 'Select', 'NativeSelect'])) {
  136 |       return;
  137 |     }
View compiled
constructClassInstance
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11447
  11444 |   }
  11445 | }
  11446 | 
> 11447 | var instance = new ctor(props, context);
  11448 | var state = workInProgress.memoizedState = instance.state !== null && instance.state !== undefined ? instance.state : null;
  11449 | adoptClassInstance(workInProgress, instance);
  11450 | 
View compiled
updateClassComponent
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13144
  13141 | if (current === null) {
  13142 |   if (workInProgress.stateNode === null) {
  13143 |     // In the initial pass we might need to construct the instance.
> 13144 |     constructClassInstance(workInProgress, workInProgress.pendingProps, renderExpirationTime);
  13145 |     mountClassInstance(workInProgress, renderExpirationTime);
  13146 | 
  13147 |     shouldUpdate = true;
View compiled
beginWork
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13824
  13821 | case FunctionalComponent:
  13822 |   return updateFunctionalComponent(current, workInProgress);
  13823 | case ClassComponent:
> 13824 |   return updateClassComponent(current, workInProgress, renderExpirationTime);
  13825 | case HostRoot:
  13826 |   return updateHostRoot(current, workInProgress, renderExpirationTime);
  13827 | case HostComponent:
View compiled
performUnitOfWork
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15863
  15860 |   startBaseRenderTimer();
  15861 | }
  15862 | 
> 15863 | next = beginWork(current, workInProgress, nextRenderExpirationTime);
  15864 | 
  15865 | if (workInProgress.mode & ProfileMode) {
  15866 |   // Update "base" time if the render wasn't bailed out on.
View compiled
workLoop
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15902
  15899 | if (!isAsync) {
  15900 |   // Flush all expired work.
  15901 |   while (nextUnitOfWork !== null) {
> 15902 |     nextUnitOfWork = performUnitOfWork(nextUnitOfWork);
  15903 |   }
  15904 | } else {
  15905 |   // Flush asynchronous work until the deadline runs out of time.
View compiled
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:100
   97 |   // nested call would trigger the fake event handlers of any call higher
   98 |   // in the stack.
   99 |   fakeNode.removeEventListener(evtType, callCallback, false);
> 100 |   func.apply(context, funcArgs);
  101 |   didError = false;
  102 | }
  103 | 
View compiled
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:138
  135 | // Synchronously dispatch our fake event. If the user-provided function
  136 | // errors, it will trigger our global error handler.
  137 | evt.initEvent(evtType, false, false);
> 138 | fakeNode.dispatchEvent(evt);
  139 | 
  140 | if (didError) {
  141 |   if (!didSetError) {
View compiled
invokeGuardedCallback
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:187
  184 |  * @param {...*} args Arguments for function
  185 |  */
  186 | invokeGuardedCallback: function (name, func, context, a, b, c, d, e, f) {
> 187 |   invokeGuardedCallback$1.apply(ReactErrorUtils, arguments);
  188 | },
  189 | 
  190 | /**
View compiled
replayUnitOfWork
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15310
  15307 | // Replay the begin phase.
  15308 | isReplayingFailedUnitOfWork = true;
  15309 | originalReplayError = thrownValue;
> 15310 | invokeGuardedCallback$2(null, workLoop, null, isAsync);
  15311 | isReplayingFailedUnitOfWork = false;
  15312 | originalReplayError = null;
  15313 | if (hasCaughtError()) {
View compiled
renderRoot
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15962
  15959 | 
  15960 | var failedUnitOfWork = nextUnitOfWork;
  15961 | if (true && replayFailedUnitOfWorkWithInvokeGuardedCallback) {
> 15962 |   replayUnitOfWork(failedUnitOfWork, thrownValue, isAsync);
  15963 | }
  15964 | 
  15965 | // TODO: we already know this isn't true in some cases.
View compiled
performWorkOnRoot
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16560
  16557 |   // This root is already complete. We can commit it.
  16558 |   completeRoot(root, finishedWork, expirationTime);
  16559 | } else {
> 16560 |   finishedWork = renderRoot(root, expirationTime, false);
  16561 |   if (finishedWork !== null) {
  16562 |     // We've completed the root. Commit it.
  16563 |     completeRoot(root, finishedWork, expirationTime);
View compiled
performWork
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16482
  16479 |   }
  16480 | } else {
  16481 |   while (nextFlushedRoot !== null && nextFlushedExpirationTime !== NoWork && (minExpirationTime === NoWork || minExpirationTime >= nextFlushedExpirationTime)) {
> 16482 |     performWorkOnRoot(nextFlushedRoot, nextFlushedExpirationTime, false);
  16483 |     findHighestPriorityRoot();
  16484 |   }
  16485 | }
View compiled
performSyncWork
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16454
  16451 | }
  16452 | 
  16453 | function performSyncWork() {
> 16454 |   performWork(Sync, false, null);
  16455 | }
  16456 | 
  16457 | function performWork(minExpirationTime, isAsync, dl) {
View compiled
requestWork
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16354
  16351 | 
  16352 | // TODO: Get rid of Sync and use current time?
  16353 | if (expirationTime === Sync) {
> 16354 |   performSyncWork();
  16355 | } else {
  16356 |   scheduleCallbackWithExpiration(expirationTime);
  16357 | }
View compiled
scheduleWork$1
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16218
  16215 | !isWorking || isCommitting$1 ||
  16216 | // ...unless this is a different root than the one we're rendering.
  16217 | nextRoot !== root) {
> 16218 |   requestWork(root, nextExpirationTimeToWorkOn);
  16219 | }
  16220 | if (nestedUpdateCount > NESTED_UPDATE_LIMIT) {
  16221 |   invariant(false, 'Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.');
View compiled
scheduleRootUpdate
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16785
  16782 |   }
  16783 |   enqueueUpdate(current, update, expirationTime);
  16784 | 
> 16785 |   scheduleWork$1(current, expirationTime);
  16786 |   return expirationTime;
  16787 | }
  16788 | 
View compiled
updateContainerAtExpirationTime
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16812
  16809 |     container.pendingContext = context;
  16810 |   }
  16811 | 
> 16812 |   return scheduleRootUpdate(current, element, expirationTime, callback);
  16813 | }
  16814 | 
  16815 | function findHostInstance(component) {
View compiled
updateContainer
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16839
  16836 |   var current = container.current;
  16837 |   var currentTime = recalculateCurrentTime();
  16838 |   var expirationTime = computeExpirationForFiber(currentTime, current);
> 16839 |   return updateContainerAtExpirationTime(element, container, parentComponent, expirationTime, callback);
  16840 | }
  16841 | 
  16842 | function getPublicRootInstance(container) {
View compiled
ReactRoot../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17122
  17119 |   if (callback !== null) {
  17120 |     work.then(callback);
  17121 |   }
> 17122 |   updateContainer(children, root, null, work._onCommit);
  17123 |   return work;
  17124 | };
  17125 | ReactRoot.prototype.unmount = function (callback) {
View compiled
(anonymous function)
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17262
  17259 |     if (parentComponent != null) {
  17260 |       root.legacy_renderSubtreeIntoContainer(parentComponent, children, callback);
  17261 |     } else {
> 17262 |       root.render(children, callback);
  17263 |     }
  17264 |   });
  17265 | } else {
View compiled
unbatchedUpdates
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16679
  16676 |       isUnbatchingUpdates = false;
  16677 |     }
  16678 |   }
> 16679 |   return fn(a);
  16680 | }
  16681 | 
  16682 | // TODO: Batching should be implemented at the renderer level, not within
View compiled
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17258
  17255 |   };
  17256 | }
  17257 | // Initial mount should not be batched.
> 17258 | unbatchedUpdates(function () {
  17259 |   if (parentComponent != null) {
  17260 |     root.legacy_renderSubtreeIntoContainer(parentComponent, children, callback);
  17261 |   } else {
View compiled
render
D:/SC/projectPath/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17317
  17314 |   return legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer(null, element, container, true, callback);
  17315 | },
  17316 | render: function (element, container, callback) {
> 17317 |   return legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer(null, element, container, false, callback);
  17318 | },
  17319 | unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer: function (parentComponent, element, containerNode, callback) {
  17320 |   !(parentComponent != null && has(parentComponent)) ? invariant(false, 'parentComponent must be a valid React Component') : void 0;
View compiled
./src/index.js
D:/SC/projectPath/src/index.js:9
   6 | import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
   7 | import 'babel-polyfill';
   8 | 
>  9 | ReactDOM.render(
  10 |   <Provider store={store}>
  11 |     <App />
  12 |   </Provider>, document.querySelector('#root')
```

My `package.json` file looks as follows

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-available-tasks": "^0.6.3",
    "grunt-check-dependencies": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-npm-command": "^0.1.2",
    "grunt-run": "^0.8.0",
    "json-server": "^0.14.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.7.9",
    "react-mutation-observer": "^1.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.54",
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.3.0"
  }
```

Comment: I have same problem too.

Answer (score 2):

I inherited a project which was originally on Material-UI beta, and when I updated to 2.x.x version I started getting this error.

The issue for me was how the components were imported. In the alpha and beta versions (and potentially 1.x.x), some components were secondary exports from another component. ie.

`import List, { ListItem } from "@material-ui/core/List";`

In the new version, every component is a default export from its own file, which means you would have to import `ListItem` as such:
`import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";`

For simplicity's sake (since I had to update *many* imports) I used the following shortcut:

`import { List, ListItem } from "@material-ui/core";`

Bottom line is the new version of Material-UI was trying to parse and element that didn't exist as an export from that file, and threw an error saying it didn't understand what you were giving it. This was probably covered in a migration doc somewhere but it would've been nice to get a more robust error message.

Answer (score 0):

My problem - and perhaps yours - is somewhat different from the above question, but the root cause is the same: MaterialUI import syntax.

A tip of the hat to Joseph Spens' answer, since his solution provided the clues to identify my own problem. The problem was caused by accepting VSCode's QuickFix *(and probably choosing the first option)*.

**This was the problem:**

```
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
```

**This was the fix:**

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
```

Not quite the same problem/solution as Joseph's, but certainly related.

Comment: Reminder [about offering voting advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63640931). You can forego reputation by marking your post as Community Wiki if you wish, but I wouldn't bother - it is best to let people vote organically.