# jquery: progressbar grow from center of the page

Tags: jquery, css

i many time work with bootstrap progress bar. a small example attached.

```
var $progress = $('.progress');
var $progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
var $alert = $('.alert');

setTimeout(function() {
    $progressBar.css('width', '10%');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $progressBar.css('width', '30%');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $progressBar.css('width', '100%');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $progress.css('display', 'none');
                $alert.css('display', 'block');
            }, 500); // WAIT 5 milliseconds
        }, 2000); // WAIT 2 seconds
    }, 1000); // WAIT 1 seconds
}, 1000); // WAIT 1 second
```

full code can be found from here https://jsfiddle.net/qLgv2Lfm/8/

recently i saw a nice progress bar at **linked in web site**. say when we click on any link then progress bar grow from top center of the page to both end mean left and right side. i feel it looks nice to me. so anyone can check **linked in site** progress and tell me idea how to develop such kind of progress bar.

[image]

one image given just see very minutely then must notice a very thin deep blue line grow from center-top of the page below home | network menu etc.

if i search youtube like progress bar then we can get many code sample but when i search **linked in web site** like progress bar then i got no write up or any concept. so anyone can discuss on this matter like how to develop **linked in web site** like progress bar. thanks

Comment: at least use jquery delay(), those timeout really not needed, or use transition in css.

Comment: i update my question. please read it minutely that what i am after.

Comment: This is just a css coding excersize that you want someone else to do for you...

Hint : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451909/expand-div-from-the-middle-instead-of-just-top-and-left-using-css

Comment: Your question is  too broad for this forum @MonojitSarkar, answers to your question will vary greatly because there is a number of ways to implement a single thing. I suggest you just try to implement what you are after, and if you run into problems ask a different question. This forum is not meant for people to find solutions for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like this question as you have not shown any attempt..

However, just use `CSS` with transitions triggered.

http://jsfiddle.net/xcWge/1848/

AS you can see we specify a transition on the loader element, in this case `square`

`<div id="square"></div>`

CSS :

`#square {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 100px; /*for centering purposes*/
    margin-left:200px;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
    -ms-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
    transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
}`

Then for example purposes, we specify the `hover` attributes to be our loading status..

`#square:hover {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}`

With some playing around, you can do what you're looking to achieve.

Related Post : [Expand div from the middle instead of just top and left using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451909/expand-div-from-the-middle-instead-of-just-top-and-left-using-css)

Edit: You can work out the Javascript section of adding and removing those attributes for progress, but your `setTimeouts` really need to be refactored.