# hovering parent div changes 0-width child div to match contained image width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several divs, each containing an icon and a tooltip-type image:

- The container is square, `height=135px` and `width=135px`.
- The icon div is mostly square, has `height=135px`, `width=auto`, it's image `height=100%` and `width=auto`to keep aspect ratio. The width is smaller than the height.
- The tooltip is rectangular, `height=135px`, `width=auto`, it's image `height=100%` and `width=auto`. The width is usually at least two times larger than the height.

The images are aligned with Bootstrap 4 classes.

Together, the container divs form up a kind of mosaic of services.  When each icon image is hovered, the corresponding tooltip-like image appears with a "book opening" animation, from the center of the icon. What I mean is, the child div has `width:0;` until the parent is hovered, then it animates to `width:[width of contained image];`. The markup is as follows:

```
    <!-- container div -->        
    <div class="int_Sicon mx-2 my-2">

        <!-- div containing the icon -->
        <a href="corresponding service page">                       
            <div class="d-block dLarge">
                <img height="100%" src="the icon url">
            </div>
        </a>

        <!-- div containing the tooltip -->
        <div class="int_Stooltip dLarge">
            <img height="100%" src="the tooltip url">
        </div>

    </div>
```

I had a buggy css animation doing what I wanted for a specific "tooltip" image, for layout testing purposes (the following css code), but it all broke apart when I finished testing and started adding the rest of the images. I had specific widths set, and utilized the `left` property to achieve what I intended, but right now I'm finishing development and wanted to allow the user to change images without breaking the layout. Each tooltip is a different image with the same height but varying widths. This is the CSS I have right now:

```
    .dLarge { height: 135px; }
    /* for different viewports I also have different heights for the icons and tooltips, but for the sake of clarity, let's focus on "dLarge" - 135px height */  

    .int_Sicon { position:relative; }
    .int_Sicon .int_Stooltip {
        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
        pointer-events: none;

        top:0;
        left: 0;
        margin:0;

        -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-out, left 0.3s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease-out, left 0.3s ease-out;
        -o-transition: width 0.3s ease-out, left 0.3s ease-out;
        transition: width 0.3s ease-out, left 0.3s ease-out;
    }
    .int_Sicon .int_Stooltip::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
    }
    .int_Sicon:hover .int_Stooltip {
        visibility: visible;
        left: -100%;
    }
```

So I started messing around with javascript and this is where I ended up, unsucessfully:

```
    var getWidth = $('.int_Stooltip>img').outerWidth();

    $('.int_Stooltip').css({'width' : 0});
    $('.int_Sicon').hover( $('.int_Sicon>.int_Stooltip').css({'width' : getWidth}); );
```

I looked everywhere for a solution, but nothing I find quite suits what I want to accomplish.
I based myself on this StackOverflow question: [Expand div from the middle instead of just top and left using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451909/expand-div-from-the-middle-instead-of-just-top-and-left-using-css)

Essentially, I wanted to make something on the lines of this https://codepen.io/wintr/pen/wWoRVW except with an image covering the button instead of a background animation.

I'm using Bootstrap 4.0 beta 2 and Jquery 3.2.1.

I'm self taught, and eager to learn more. What am I missing? Or at least, where should I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I woke up especially inspired this morning and came up with the solution. The answer wasn't in defining the widths of the divs, but specifying css for the images themselves. This is what I came up with.

Markup:

```
<div class="dLarge int_Sicon mx-2 my-2">
    <a href="corresponding service page">                       
        <div class="d-block">
            <img class="dLargeImg m-auto d-block" src="imgsrc">
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="int_Stooltip">
        <img class="dLargeImgs m-auto d-block" src="imgsrc">
    </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.dLarge {
    height: 135px; 
    width: 135px;
}

.dLargeImgs { height:135px; }

.int_Sicon {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.int_Sicon .int_Stooltip {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;

    margin:0;
    z-index: 1;

    pointer-events: none;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out, right 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out, right 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out, right 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out, right 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.int_Sicon:hover .int_Stooltip {
    left:-50%;
    right:-50%;
}

.int_Sicon .int_Stooltip img {
    width:0; 

    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out}

.int_Sicon:hover .int_Stooltip img { width:100%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to achieve the effect in the code pen example. You'll want to have your tooltip centered by default with a width of 0. You can center an absolutely positioned element by setting its top, right, bottom, and left properties to 0, then setting its margins to auto. Then when you hover, the width should change to 100%. Check out the code below. I added some colors and text just to help visualize it since there were no actual images.

```css
.int_Slogo {position:relative; display:inline-block;}
.int_Slogo .int_Stooltip {
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-out, left 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease-out, left 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s ease-out, left 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: width 0.3s ease-out, left 0.3s ease-out;
}
.int_Slogo:hover .int_Stooltip {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="int_Slogo mx-2 my-2">
    <a href="Services">                     
        <div class="d-block dLarge">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/Dummy-Text/">
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="int_Stooltip dLarge">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/Dummy-Text/">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I have. your answer doesn't  take into account the images my code has. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question, sorry.

Comment: That is not what you had in your original question. I encourage you to look more closely. I also added images in there to show how it can wok with images. It can work with any image at this point.

Comment: I edited the question for clarification. I wrote the question at the end of a frustrating day and I was tired, sorry for the confusion. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Your answer helped me get to the solution, though. Thanks!